# Datatype conversion error in pentaho

Tags: pentaho, type-conversion, kettle, pdi

Hi I have a table column named "sku" which of type integer and another column "total_sku" which again is of type integer , when I'm trying to calculate the percentage(100 * sku/total_sku) using **Calculator** step. I'm expecting an integer but its giving me 0.00 , kindly help
Thanks in advance.

```
sku   total_sku   percentage
 23      2115       1.087
 40      2115       1.891
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the calculator is doing the division before the multiplication, computing 100*(A/B), rather than (100*A)/B.  Since you are dealing with integers, it is rounding A/B down to zero, and that is the end of it for you.

The calculator step lets you break a calculation down into multiple smaller components, all within the step.  You can even specify which fields created in those substeps should stay in the stream, and which should are temporary values that should be discarded.

So try first doing a calculation such as tempValue = 100*A, then result = tempValue/B.  Set Value type to Integer in both steps.

Comment: yes, rounding both the columns served the answer for my query, thanks @ken Clubok

Answer (score 0):

In the Calculator step, put 'Value type' as 'Integer'

Comment: Nope @kaustav Its not working, now in the result its giving me '0'

Comment: It seems to work fine for me, are you sure you selected 100*A/B instead of A/B ?

Comment: yes I'm sure that I have selected 100*A/B  and not A/B.